# How to use the verbs "wipe" and "root"

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

If we have to say something like the following, would you please correct the two sentences below?

Given that we hope something:

- What we hope: we will be free from certain people.
- Which people: those who are really bad-tempered or ill-tempered, implied a negative personality, and we hate them. And, we don't want them to exist in our society. They would be quickly angry and so on.

It must be remembered by that I mean those people whom we hate them ***just for their manners or bad tempers***, not just their self. They might be considered good people but their manners are very bad as I have said above.

> I hope the society will be rooted out of them

or

> I hope they will be wiped off the face of earth from the society.

Comment: if you actually feel this way about anyone, i'm very sorry for you. but good question regardless!

Comment: When you say *rooted out*, we understand that you want them to be taken from their homes and put in prison, or badly hurt. When you say *wiped off the face of the earth* we understand that you want to murder them. You want to kill them. Is this what you want to say?

Comment: My question is this: are you referring to a particular group of people that can be named or referred to with a proper noun?

Comment: You use "we" five times in this post. This use is ambiguous. Could you define who you mean by "we". Do you mean a specific group of people, which can be identified with a proper noun? Do you mean "people in general"? Do you include yourself in this group of "we"?

Comment: We often use *I* in example sentences, as a generic subject. When you use *I* in these two sentences, are you referring to yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I comment on the actual English, I must say be **very very VERY** careful with this kind of language. Most people will be shocked and horrified to hear someone say that kind of thing. And it doesn't really matter *why* you dislike these people, this is still wildly inappropriate to say, as it sounds like you are proposing the equivalent of the holocaust. However, this is still a valid question, and I will try to answer it.

Your first sentence sounds awkward. The verb "root" is usually followed by "out" so you could say "I hope they will be rooted out of society". Another phrase that means the same thing is "weeded out".

The second sentence sounds fine except for the very end. I would remove the part about society, and say "I hope they are wiped off the face of the earth." (Except that I still absolutely **do not** recommend saying this)

Comment: I agree, but want to point out **why** this would sound shocking or horrifying (thus probably shouldn't be used): this kind of wording makes it sounds like one is expressing a xenophobic desire that genocide be committed, rather than something more positive like a desire to be left alone, or a desire that people behave more nicely. This is because the wording is focused on getting rid of the actual people, rather than their behavior, and because of the reality of xenophobia and genocides in recent history.